# how how can I work ? $x^4 + 2 x^3 - 6 x^2 - 6 x + 25=0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Solve $\frac{x^2+x-5}{x}+\frac{3x+4}{x^2+x-5}=0 $

we know $x(x^2+x-5)\neq 0$ so we have $(x^2+x-5)^2+3x^2+4x=0 \to x^4 + 2 x^3 - 6 x^2 - 6 x + 25=0$
now how how can I work ?

Comment: Don't you want $(x^2+x-5)^2+x(3x+4) = (x^2+x-5)^2+3x^2+4x= 0$? You lost the $x$ on the last term.

Comment: @person i'm sorry .thats right .

Comment: Are you looking for real solutions or just any solutions?

Comment: graphically it seems as if the equation is always positive, so no real solutions.

Comment: @person That's what I am seeing as well. 4 complex solution's and no real solutions.

Comment: @person how do It prove ?

Comment: I don't see a simple solution, but I will work on it.

Comment: If you differentiate to find the local maximums and minimums, at the local minimums, the function is greater than zero. With the sign diagram, you can conclude there are no real roots (don't forget to check $x = 0, x^2+x-5 = 0$).

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = x^4 + 2 x^3 - 6 x^2 - 6 x + 25$. We have to find a perfect square $(x^2+ax+b)^2$ that is less or equal to $f(x)$, but greater than $0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comparing coefficients, $2a x^3 = 2 \Rightarrow a = 1$, and for safety, $(2b + a^2) x^2 = -7 \Rightarrow b = -4$.

Expanding gives $g(x) = (x^2+x-4)^2 = x^4 + 2x^3 - 7x^2 - 8x + 16$. We have to be careful about the $-8x$ term as it increases the value of $g(x)$ when $x$ is negative. However, we can find a suitable $c$, such that $f(x) - g(x) = x^2+2x+(9 - c) > 0$. For example, $c = 7$ works as $x^2+2x+2$ $ = (x+1)^2 + 1 > 0$, since $u^2 ≥ 0, u \in \mathbb R$.

Thus $f(x) ≥ (x^2+2x-4)^2 + 7 > 0$.

Now just verify that when $x = 0, x^2+x-5=0$, the function is greater than $0$. Hence there are no real roots, and $4$ complex roots by the fundamental theorem of algebra.